# How to selectively enable background processing in iOS4

Tags: xcode, ios4, core-location, background-process

I have successfully enabled background processing for my Core Location app.  In order to ensure I am on the right track here is a quick overview of how I implemented ENTERING background mode:

1:  info.plist: Added key "Required background modes" with value "App registers for location updates"

2:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}
```

When EXITING background mode I did so with this code:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

This seems to be working well as I am getting locations reported while my iPhone is off.  Any advice on whether this approach is considered "best practice" would be appreciated.

My concern is that even when my app is explicitly terminated on the iPhone the Location Services arrow still shows on the status bar.

My question is:  Is it possible to programatically enable/disable an application's background processing?

My reason for this is that if my user does not want to use the location awareness portion of my app, I would like to prevent the app from processing in the background, even if it is not receiving locations.

Thanks and much for any info!

---

Thank-you for your prompt answers.  What seems to be happening is that even though I issue

```
[self.locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

and

```
[self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

the Location Services arrow thingy on the status bar stays on, even when my app has exited.  I have force terminated it as well, but the arrow stays on.

I also have no other apps that are running as suspended.  I have looked in Settings > Location Services > MyApp and see that both myApp and the built-in Maps app indicate that they are currently using Location Services, however, neither is actually running.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?  Could it be that I am not freeing up resources properly when my app either goes into the background or terminates?

All answers are much appreciated.

Comment: Your implementation of background looks good, and would be considered "best practice"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a setting saved in NSUserDefaults and use that whether or not to enable your background location services.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardDefaults];
someFlag = [defaults boolForKey:@"gpsOnOff"];

if (someFlag) {
   // enable background services
}
```

Comment: Bill. I do have a user default that turns on/off Location Services.  I did not know you could turn actual background processing on/off programmatically.  I thought it was only in the info.plist.  Any suggestions on how to do it in code?  Thanks

Comment: You still have to manually code it, but you can store the state in user defaults so you can have access to it easily in your AppDel or any other location you need to determine whether or not to use use location.